# When installing Nginx, the nginx directory is not created in the etc directory

Tags: python-3.x, nginx, virtual-machine

I'm working on a training project.
Reinstalled nginx, but when installing in etc, nginx does not appear. What should I do in this case?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfFUs.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7lJ9i.png)

The sudo apt-get install nginx command installs nginx, but I can't run it anymore.
Logs indicate the absence of a file or directory
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OpAuX.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try `whereis nginx` to see where is the nginx beed installed

Comment: nginx: /usr/sbin/nginx /usr/lib/nginx /usr/share/nginx /usr/share/man/man8/nginx.8.gz

Answer (score 0):

After a complete clean up, I see the same today, so I try with:

`apt install nginx-core`

Don't know why nginx-full does not creates the directory, but nginx-core does.

tested on debian

Try and tell us :)